# Image Not Shown In IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I faced some problems after hosting my web project in IIS 7 / Windows 2008. Images are not shown when I run the project on my browser.

I copied my project folder (webtest) to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\`. To be sure, I chose image from `webtest\image\sample.jpg` again. It works properly when I run it. However, after putting up for hosting and I call it from browser it doesn't show the image.

What are the possible causes of the problem?

Comment: fellow Singaporean. Please don't throw our country's face by not formatting your post properly. #Patriotism

Comment: where did you put the image on the server? what is shown if the image is not shown?

Comment: hi thephpdeveloper,i found out what happen?but,i still finding the solution.image is not show when i browse like this "http://localhost/WebTest/Start",after i add "/" behind of this url,it shown.i dont' know what happen?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to add .jpg/.jpeg mime type in IIS Manager if it doesn't exists.

[image]